# UnsupportedOperationException when using Method Pointer Operator and MockFor

Tags: groovy

I had a test. It was using mockFor and was working and I was happy. Until something changed and I was forced to use a method pointer operator, and then my happiness was a just a memory.

Here a constricted example of the problem

```
import groovy.mock.interceptor.*

// I am testing againts a interface, not an actual class
// this is not negociable.
interface Person {
    void sayHello(name);
}

// Setup (can do whatever I need)
def personMock = new MockFor(Person)
personMock.demand.sayHello { name -> println "Hello $name" }
def person = personMock.proxyInstance()
// End Setup

// Exercise (can not change)
def closureMethod = person.&sayHello.curry("Groovy!")
closureMethod()
// End Exercise

personMock.verify(person)
```

Which would be the safest and simplest way to fix the test?
Currently, the test fails with `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even when I am testing against a Interface, nothing prevents me from creating a mock class that implements the interface and do a poor-men verify demands.

```
import groovy.mock.interceptor.*

// I am testing against a interface, not an actual class
// this is not negociable.
interface Person {
    void sayHello(name);
}

class PersonMock implements Person {
    def calls = []
    void sayHello(name) { calls << "sayHello" }
}

// Setup (can do whatever I need)
def person = new PersonMock()
// End Setup

// Exercise (can not change)
def closureMethod = person.&sayHello.curry("Groovy!")
closureMethod()
// End Exercise

assert person.calls == ['sayHello']
```